# pl/sql case from a select value

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to have a case statement from a select like:

```
select buyer id,
buyer_add
buyer_city,
buyer_state,
 , case
    when Special_Desc  like "%ma%" then "Mail"
    when Special_Desc like "%pa%" then "phone"
    else " "
end as Special_Handling 
         from
            ( select string_func(buyer_id) 
              from advance.pledge p) Special_Desc
from buyer_info
    where..
```

In other words, I need to do a case on Special_desc that will be produced from a Select Statement

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi this is an example which illustrates how to use case within a select statement. I hope this query resolves your problem. Please let me know for any issues. Thanks

SELECT sr_no,
(SELECT
CASE
WHEN UPPER(name)=UPPER('Avrajit') THEN 'My_name1'
WHEN UPPER(name)=UPPER('Shubhojit') THEN 'My_name2'
 END FROM Avrajit
) AS condition
FROM avrajit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should something like this:

```
select buyer id,
       buyer_add
       buyer_city,
       buyer_state,
       case
         when regexp_like(s.Special_Desc, 'ma*', 'i') then 'Mail'
         when regexp_like(s.Special_Desc, 'pa*', 'i') then 'Phone'
         else ' '
      end as Special_Handling 
from ( select string_func(buyer_id) 
        from advance.pledge p) s,
     buyer_info
where..
```

Of cousr you need to correlate the two tables.

Comment: Thank you, I changed this part from your query: from ( select string_func(buyer_id) from advance.pledge p) s,   to:from ( select string_func(buyer_id) 
        from advance.pledge p)special_Desc,
but now its telling me that missing right parenthesis and all parentesis are correct

Comment: This is my actual code but now it is giving me 'Missing rigth parenthesis , case when Sp_Desc like('ma%') then 'mail' when Sp_Desc like('pa%') then 'phone' else " " end AS Special_Handling from ( string_function(g.buyer_id) from gift g ) AS Sp_Desc

Comment: you cannot use %, this is not a regular expression

Comment: Steve the % is used as wildcard

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using the function inside of the case statement.
case
         when STRING_FUNCTION(g.gift_donor_id) like('%MA%' )
        then 'MAIL'
       when STRING_FUNCTION(g.gift_donor_id) like('%MA%' )
       then 'Phone'
         else ' '
       end as Special_H

Thanks all for your valuable help.